# Shared Folders not appearing in Outlook for new user

Tags: outlook

I have attempted to google for this answer, but I haven't found a solution that works.

**I am not part of the IT area, so I won't have access to the Exchange server itself

Windows 7, Outlook 2010

What is occurring is that whenever they give permission to this mailbox, the person receiving permission cannot see the shared folders and subfolders within it. The only way to do it is to go folder by folder and do it manually.

I have tried checking and unchecking the 'Download Shared Folders' box.

I know that they have set themselves as 'owners', but I believe there is a level above that permission-wise? Could that be the issue of why everything isn't showing up?

Sorry for the vague information, but it is about the best I can describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with your IT department and see if they are giving the users "Full Control" to the mailbox from the Exchange admin console. That is the permission that allows you to access the mailbox as if it was yours.